# Development Pod doesn't recognize a class in the main target

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

i separated the **networkLayer** and **DatabaseLayer** in my project into different **development pods** ,
i faced an issue where the networkLayer is dependent on a class that exists in my main target

i tried editing the **podspec** of the networkLayer where i put the directory of that class , but still it doesn't recognize it

is it doable ?

Comment: This is a design issue rather than a pod config issue. You need to remove that dependency by refactoring your code.

Comment: Hello Joakim ,Thanks for your response ,  do you suggest creating a pod containing that class and import it when needed ?

Comment: No I don't suggest anything specific since I don't know about your code and how it is structured, I am just saying that the solution here is to remove the dependency by refactoring your code.

Comment: Thanks Joakim for your help